# How to delete the faint lines and add shadow on my table (only happens in IE/edge)?

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

When opening the display on IE/edge, I realized there are some faint white lines as seen in the image attached.

[image]

Apart from that, IE is not displaying what I am looking for unlike in Chrome/Firefox. There is shadow on the exterior border of the table.

[image]

I have attached my fiddle code in the comment section.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Asset Monitoring Terminal</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<style>
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
}
html 
{
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family:Book Antiqua;
}
body 
{
    max-height: 100vh;
    max-width: 100vw;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family:Book Antiqua;
}


div.img_txt
{
height:10vh;
text-align:left;
color:blue;
font-size:3vw;              
font-weight: bold;
font-family:Book Antiqua;
}
td.panel_txt
{       
text-align:center;
color:black;
font-size:4vh;              
font-weight: bold;
font-family:Book Antiqua;
width: 98vw;
height:6vh;
background-color: #DCD9D4; 
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0.50) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.50) 100%), radial-gradient(at 50% 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.10) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.50) 50%); 
 background-blend-mode: soft-light,screen;
}

div.box_shadow 
{   
box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
div.grad_box {
height: 6vh;
line-height: 6vh;
font-size:4vh;
padding:0.5vh 0.5vw 0.5vh 0.5vw;
background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(191,210,85,1) 0%, rgba(114,170,0,1) 50%, rgba(158,203,45,1) 100%);
text-align:center;
color:white;
font-weight: bold;
font-family:Book Antiqua;
}
div.txt_box {
  height: 2vw;
  line-height: 2vw;
  font-size:1.45vw;
  padding:0.25vh 0.25vw 0.25vh 0.25vw;
  text-align:center;
  color:black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family:Book Antiqua;
   white-space: nowrap;
}

div.table2_txt{
height: 4vh;
line-height:1.5vw;
font-size:1.5vw;
font-weight: bold;
font-family:Book Antiqua;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family:Book Antiqua;
  position: relative;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td.table2_row
{
width:20vw;
height:4vh;
text-align:left;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
td.table2_row1
{
width:30vw;
height:4vh;
text-align:left;
word-wrap: break-word;
}

div.table2_head{
color:blue;
height: 5vh;
line-height: 1.5vw;
font-size:1.5vw;
font-weight: bold;
font-family:Book Antiqua;
}


meter {

  width: 22vw;
  height: 3vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #777, #ddd);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black,
              inset 2px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3),
              inset -2px -3px 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    border-radius: 3px;

}



.legend_meter{
    width:4vw;
    height: 4vh;
    border:solid 1px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #777, #ddd);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black,
              inset 2px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3),
              inset -2px -3px 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-left:3vw;

}
.button {

    font-size: 3vh;
    line-height: 3vh;
    padding:0.5vh 0.5vw 0.5vh 0.5vw;
    height:4vh;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family:Book Antiqua;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3vh;
  box-shadow: 0 1vh #999;
}

.button:hover 
{
background-color: #3e8e41
}
.button:active 
{
  background-color: #3e8e41;
  box-shadow: 0 0.5vh #666;
  transform: translateY(0.5vh);
}
.thresh_table
{
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: relative;
    top: -46.5vh;
    transform: scale(0.8);
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family:Book Antiqua;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);

}
.inp_type
{
    border-radius: 10%;
    border: 1px solid #609;
    width: 4vw;
    height: 3vh;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family:Book Antiqua;
    font-size:1.25vw;
    line-height:1.25vw;
}

.thresh_box{
    height: 4vh;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family:Book Antiqua;
    font-size: 3vh;
    line-height: 3vh;
    text-align: center;
}
.td_spec 
{
text-align:left;
font-size: 2.5vh;
line-height: 2.5vh;
padding:0.5vh 0.5vw 0.5vh 0.5vw;
}

.meter_val
{
font-weight:bold;
font-family:Book Antiqua;
font-size:1.25vw;
line-height:1.25vw;
margin-left:0.5vw;
}

</style>
</head><body>
<table style="margin-left: 1vw;margin-top: 2vh;">
 <tr>
 <td style="text-align:left;max-height:8vh;">
 <span style="font-size: 6vh;background-image:linear-gradient(120deg, #d4fc79 0%, #96e6a1 100%);color:black;padding:1vh 1vw 1vh 1vw;">P-54A</span>
   </td>
 </tr>

</table>


<table style="margin-top: 3vh;margin-left: 1vw;margin-right: 1vw;">
   <tr>
   <td class="panel_txt">Metering</td>
   </tr>
</table>



<table style="margin-top: 5vh;">
    <tr>
    <td style="width:3.3vw;height:10vh;"></td>
    <td style="width:16vw;height:10vh;"><div class="box_shadow"><div id="speed" class="grad_box"></div><div class="txt_box" >Speed (rpm)</div></div></td>
    <td style="width:3.3vw;height:10vh;"></td>
    <td style="width:16vw;height:10vh;"><div class="box_shadow"><div id="loading" class="grad_box"></div><div class="txt_box" >Loading (%) </div></div></td>
    <td style="width:3.3vw;height:10vh;"></td>
    <td style="width:16vw;height:10vh;"><div class="box_shadow"><div id="rms_vel" class="grad_box"></div><div class="txt_box" >Overall velocity (mm/s) </div></div></td>
    <td style="width:3.3vw;height:10vh;"></td>
    <td style="width:16vw;height:10vh;"><div class="box_shadow"><div id="rms_acc" class="grad_box"></div><div class="txt_box" >Acceleration-rms (m/s) </div></div></td>
    <td style="width:3.3vw;height:10vh;"></td>
    <td style="width:16vw;height:10vh;"><div class="box_shadow"><div id="peak_acc" class="grad_box"></div><div class="txt_box" >Acceleration-peak (m/s) </div></div></td>
    <td style="width:3.3vw;height:10vh;"></td>
   </tr>

</table>

<table style="margin-top: 5vh;margin-left: 1vw;margin-right: 1vw;">
   <tr>
   <td class="panel_txt">Monitoring and diagnostics</td>
   </tr>
</table>

<table style="margin-top: 5vh;margin-left: 4vw;" >

  <tr>
   <td  bgcolor="#ffebe6" colspan="2" style="padding:0.25vh 0 0.25vh 0;width:50vw;height:5vh;text-align:center;border-style:ridge;border-color:#ff9980;border-width:0.5vh;border-bottom:none;"><div class="table2_head"> Vibration</div></td>
    <td style="width:25vw;height:5vh;"></td>
    <td style="width:25vw;height:5vh;"></td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#ffebe6" class="table2_row" style="border-style:ridge;border-color:#ff9980;border-width:0.5vh;border-bottom:none;border-top:none;border-right:none;"><div class="table2_txt" style="margin-left:1vw;" >Overall velocity </div></td>
    <td bgcolor="#ffebe6" class="table2_row1" style="border-style:ridge;border-color:#ff9980;border-width:0.5vh;border-bottom:none;border-top:none;border-left:none;"><meter id="velocity" style="height:3vh;" value="0">2</meter><span id ="c1" class="meter_val"></span><label for="c1" class="meter_val" style="margin-left:0.25vh;color:grey;">mm/s</label></td>
    <td style="width:25vw;height:4vh;"></td>
    <td style="width:25vw;height:4vh;"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#ffebe6" class="table2_row" style="border-style:ridge;border-color:#ff9980;border-width:0.5vh;border-bottom:none;border-top:none;border-right:none;"><div class="table2_txt" style="color:grey;margin-left:4vw;font-style: italic;" >Unbalance</div></td>
    <td  bgcolor="#ffebe6" class="table2_row1" style="border-style:ridge;border-color:#ff9980;border-width:0.5vh;border-bottom:none;border-top:none;border-left:none;"><meter id="Unbalance" style="height:2vh;width:15vw;" value="0"></meter><span id ="c2" class="meter_val" ></span><label for="c2" class="meter_val" style="margin-left:0.25vh;color:grey;">%</label></td>
    <td style="width:25vw;height:4vh;"></td>
    <td style="width:25vw;height:4vh;"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#ffebe6" class="table2_row" style="border-style:ridge;border-color:#ff9980;border-width:0.5vh;border-bottom:none;border-top:none;border-right:none;"><div class="table2_txt" style="color:grey;margin-left:4vw;font-style: italic;" >Misalignment</div></td>
    <td bgcolor="#ffebe6" class="table2_row1" style="border-style:ridge;border-color:#ff9980;border-width:0.5vh;border-bottom:none;border-top:none;border-left:none;"><meter id="Misalignment" style="height:2vh;width:15vw;"  value="0"></meter><span id ="c3" class="meter_val" ></span><label for="c3" class="meter_val" style="margin-left:0.25vh;color:grey;">%</label></td>
    <td style="width:25vw;height:4vh;"><span><meter class="legend_meter" value="3" min="0" max="3" optimum="3"></span> <span style="text-align:left;line-height:3vh;font-size:3vh;font-weight:bold;font-family:Book Antiqua;margin-left:1vw;">Satisfactory</span></td>
    <td style="width:25vw;height:4vh;"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#ffebe6" class="table2_row" style="border-style:ridge;border-color:#ff9980;border-width:0.5vh;border-bottom:none;border-top:none;border-right:none;"><div class="table2_txt" style="color:grey;margin-left:4vw;font-style: italic;" >Looseness</div></td>
    <td bgcolor="#ffebe6" class="table2_row1" style="border-style:ridge;border-color:#ff9980;border-width:0.5vh;border-bottom:none;border-top:none;border-left:none;"><meter id="Looseness" style="height:2vh;width:15vw;"  value="0"></meter><span id ="c4" class="meter_val"></span><label for="c4" class="meter_val" style="margin-left:0.25vh;color:grey;">%</label></td>
    <td style="width:25vw;height:4vh;"><span><meter class="legend_meter" value="3" min="0" max="3"  low="2" ></span><span style="text-align:left;line-height:3vh;font-size:3vh;font-weight:bold;font-family:Book Antiqua;margin-left:1vw;">Unsatisfactory</span></td>
    <td align="left" style="width:25vw;height:4vh;"><button class="button" style="height:4vh;"onclick="openthresh()">Calibrate threshold</button></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#ffebe6" class="table2_row" style="border-style:ridge;border-color:#ff9980;border-width:0.5vh;border-top:none;border-right:none;"><div class="table2_txt" style="margin-left:1vw;" >Bearing</div> </td>
    <td bgcolor="#ffebe6" class="table2_row1" style="border-style:ridge;border-color:#ff9980;border-width:0.5vh;border-top:none;border-left:none;"><meter id="bearing" style="height:3vh;" value="0" min="-1" max="2" optimum="0" low="0.9" high="1.9"></meter></td>
    <td style="width:25vw;height:4vh;"><span><meter class="legend_meter" value="3" min="0" max="3" optimum="1" low="2" high="2.5"></span><span style="text-align:left;line-height:3vh;font-size:3vh;font-weight:bold;font-family:Book Antiqua;margin-left:1vw;">Unacceptable</span></td>
    <td style="width:25vw;height:4vh;"></td>
  </tr>

    <tr >
    <td class="table2_row" style="height:1vh;"></td>
    <td class="table2_row1" style="height:1vh;"></td>
    <td style="width:25vw;height:1vh;"></td>
    <td style="width:25vw;height:1vh;"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr >
    <td bgcolor="#e6f0ff" colspan="2" style="padding:0.25vh 0 0.25vh 0;width:50vw;height:5vh;text-align:center;border-style:ridge;border-color:#80b3ff;border-width:0.5vh;border-bottom:none;"><div class="table2_head" >Magnetic flux</div></td>
    <td style="width:25vw;height:5vh;"></td>
    <td style="width:25vw;height:5vh;"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#e6f0ff" class="table2_row" style="border-style:ridge;border-color:#80b3ff;border-width:0.5vh;border-bottom:none;border-top:none;border-right:none;"> <div class="table2_txt" style="margin-left:1vw;">Stator winding</div></td>
    <td bgcolor="#e6f0ff" class="table2_row1" style="border-style:ridge;border-color:#80b3ff;border-width:0.5vh;border-bottom:none;border-top:none;border-left:none;"><meter id="Stator" style="height:3vh;"  value="0"></meter><span id ="c6" class="meter_val"></span><label for="c6" class="meter_val" style="margin-left:0.25vh;color:grey;">%</label> </td>
    <td style="width:25vw;height:4vh;"></td>
    <td style="width:25vw;height:4vh;"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#e6f0ff" class="table2_row" style="border-style:ridge;border-color:#80b3ff;border-width:0.5vh;border-bottom:none;border-top:none;border-right:none;"> <div class="table2_txt" style="margin-left:1vw;">Rotor</div></td>
    <td bgcolor="#e6f0ff" class="table2_row1" style="border-style:ridge;border-color:#80b3ff;border-width:0.5vh;border-bottom:none;border-top:none;border-left:none;"><meter id="Rotor1" style="height:3vh;"  value="0"></meter><span id ="c7" class="meter_val"></span> <label for="c7" class="meter_val" style="margin-left:0.25vh;color:grey;">%</label></td>
    <td style="width:25vw;height:4vh;"></td>
    <td style="width:25vw;height:4vh;"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#e6f0ff" class="table2_row" style="border-style:ridge;border-color:#80b3ff;border-width:0.5vh;border-top:none;border-right:none;"> <div class="table2_txt" style="margin-left:1vw;">Unbalance/looseness</div></td>
    <td bgcolor="#e6f0ff" class="table2_row1" style="border-style:ridge;border-color:#80b3ff;border-width:0.5vh;border-top:none;border-left:none;"><meter id="Rotor2" style="height:3vh;"  value="0"></meter><span id ="c8" class="meter_val"></span> <label for="c8" class="meter_val" style="margin-left:0.25vh;color:grey;">%</label></td>
    <td style="width:25vw;height:4vh;"></td>
    <td style="width:25vw;height:4vh;"></td>
  </tr>

</table>

<!-- <table class ="thresh_table" style="min-width: 42vw;max-width: 42vw;margin-left:54vw;margin-right:1vw;" id="threshtable"> -->
<table class ="thresh_table" style="margin-left:56vw;margin-right:4vw;" id="threshtable">
<tr style="border-style:ridge;border-color:black;border-width:1vh;border-top:none;border-bottom:none;border-right:none;border-left:none;">
<td colspan="2" style="padding:0.25vh 0 0.25vh 0;line-height: 1.5vw;font-size:1.5vw;text-align: center;width:15vw;height:4vh;background: #77aa33;opacity: 0.9;color:black;">Satisfactory</td>
<td colspan="4" style="padding:0.25vh 0 0.25vh 0;line-height: 1.5vw;font-size:1.5vw;text-align: center;width:16vw;height:4vh;background: #ddbb33;opacity: 0.9;color:black;">Unsatisfactory</td>
<td             style="padding:0.25vh 0 0.25vh 0;line-height: 1.5vw;font-size:1.5vw;text-align: center;width:11vw;height:4vh;background: #dd4444;opacity: 0.9;color:black;">Unacceptable</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style="width:11vw;height:4vh;line-height: 1.25vw;font-size:1.25vw;text-align: left;background: #77aa33;opacity: 0.9;"><div style="margin-left:0.5vw;">Overall velocity</div></div></td>
<td style="width:4vw;height:3vh;padding:0.5vh 0 0.5vh 0;background: #77aa33;opacity: 0.9;"><input class ="inp_type" id ="vel_unsat" type="number" min="1" max="200"></td>
<td colspan="3" style="width:12vw;height:4vh;background: #ddbb33;opacity: 0.9;"><label style="margin-left:0.25vh;color:black;text-align: left;">mm/s</label></td>
<td style="width:4vw;height:3vh;padding:0.5vh 0 0.5vh 0;background: #ddbb33;opacity: 0.9;"><input class ="inp_type" id ="vel_unacc" type="number" min="1" max="200"></td>
<td style="width:11vw;height:4vh;background: #dd4444;opacity: 0.9;"><label style="margin-left:0.25vh;color:black;text-align: left;">mm/s</label></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style="width:11vw;height:4vh;line-height: 1.25vw;font-size:1.25vw;text-align: left;background: #77aa33;opacity: 0.9;margin-left:1vw;"><div style="margin-left:0.5vw;">Unbalance</div></td>
<td style="width:4vw;height:3vh;padding:0.5vh 0 0.5vh 0;background: #77aa33;opacity: 0.9;"><input class ="inp_type" id ="unbal_unsat" type="number" min="1" max="200"></td>
<td colspan="3" style="width:12vw;height:4vh;background: #ddbb33;opacity: 0.9;"><label style="margin-left:0.25vh;color:black;text-align: left;  font-weight: bold;">%</label></td>
<td style="width:4vw;height:3vh;padding:0.5vh 0 0.5vh 0;background: #ddbb33;opacity: 0.9;"><input class ="inp_type" id ="unbal_unacc" type="number" min="1" max="200"></td>
<td style="width:11vw;height:4vh;background: #dd4444;opacity: 0.9;"><label style="margin-left:0.25vh;color:black;text-align:left;  font-weight: bold;">%</label></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style="width:11vw;height:4vh;line-height: 1.25vw;font-size:1.25vw;text-align: left;background: #77aa33;opacity: 0.9;margin-left:1vw;"><div style="margin-left:0.5vw;">Misalignment</div></td>
<td style="width:4vw;height:3vh;padding:0.5vh 0 0.5vh 0;background: #77aa33;opacity: 0.9;"><input class ="inp_type" id ="misal_unsat" type="number" min="1" max="200"></td>
<td colspan="3" style="width:12vw;height:4vh;background: #ddbb33;opacity: 0.9;"><label style="margin-left:0.25vh;color:black;text-align: left;  font-weight: bold;">%</label></td>
<td style="width:4vw;height:3vh;padding:0.5vh 0 0.5vh 0;background: #ddbb33;opacity: 0.9;"><input class ="inp_type" id ="misal_unacc" type="number" min="1" max="200"></td>
<td style="width:11vw;height:4vh;background: #dd4444;opacity: 0.9;"><label style="margin-left:0.25vh;color:black;text-align:left;  font-weight: bold;">%</label></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style="width:11vw;height:4vh;line-height: 1.25vw;font-size:1.25vw;text-align: left;background: #77aa33;opacity: 0.9;margin-left:1vw;"><div style="margin-left:0.5vw;">Looseness</div></td>
<td style="width:4vw;height:3vh;padding:0.5vh 0 0.5vh 0;background: #77aa33;opacity: 0.9;"><input class ="inp_type" id ="loos_unsat" type="number" min="1" max="200"></td>
<td colspan="3" style="width:12vw;height:4vh;background: #ddbb33;opacity: 0.9;"><label style="margin-left:0.25vh;color:black;text-align: left;  font-weight: bold;">%</label></td>
<td style="width:4vw;height:3vh;padding:0.5vh 0 0.5vh 0;background: #ddbb33;opacity: 0.9;"><input class ="inp_type" id ="loos_unacc" type="number" min="1" max="200"></td>
<td style="width:11vw;height:4vh;background: #dd4444;opacity: 0.9;"><label style="margin-left:0.25vh;color:black;text-align:left;  font-weight: bold;">%</label></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style="text-align:center;height:10.5vh;width:11vw;" > 
<button class="button" style="border-radius: 1vh;box-shadow: none; "onclick="submitthresh()">Submit</button>
</td>
<td colspan="5" style="text-align:center;height:10.5vh;width:20vw;font-family:Book Antiqua;font-size: 1.5vw;line-height: 1.5vw;text-align: center;" > Threshold settings</td>
<td style="text-align:center;height:10.5vh;width:11vw;"> 
<button class="button" style="border-radius: 1vh;box-shadow: none; "onclick="closethresh()">Close</button>
</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td colspan="3" style="width:19vw;height:4vh;line-height: 1.25vw;font-size:1.25vw;text-align: left;background: #77aa33;opacity: 0.9;margin-left:1vw;"><div style="margin-left:0.5vw;">Stator winding</div></td>
<td style="width:4vw;height:3vh;padding:0.5vh 0 0.5vh 0;background: #77aa33;opacity: 0.9;"><input class ="inp_type" id ="swf_unacc" type="number" min="1" max="200"></td>
<td colspan="3" style="width:19vw;height:4vh;background: #dd4444;opacity: 0.9;"><label style="margin-left:0.25vh;color:black;text-align: left;  font-weight: bold;">%</label></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="3" style="width:19vw;height:4vh;line-height: 1.25vw;font-size:1.25vw;text-align: left;background: #77aa33;opacity: 0.9;margin-left:1vw;"><div style="margin-left:0.5vw;">Rotor</div></td>
<td style="width:4vw;height:3vh;padding:0.5vh 0 0.5vh 0;background: #77aa33;opacity: 0.9;"><input class ="inp_type" id ="brb_unacc" type="number" min="1" max="200"></td>
<td colspan="3" style="width:19vw;height:4vh;background: #dd4444;opacity: 0.9;"><label style="margin-left:0.25vh;color:black;text-align: left;  font-weight: bold;">%</label></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="3" style="width:19vw;height:4vh;line-height: 1.25vw;font-size:1.25vw;text-align: left;background: #77aa33;opacity: 0.9;margin-left:1vw;"><div style="margin-left:0.5vw;">Unbalance/loosenss</div></td>
<td style="width:4vw;height:3vh;padding:0.5vh 0 0.5vh 0;background: #77aa33;opacity: 0.9;"><input class ="inp_type" id ="f_loos_unacc" type="number" min="1" max="200"></td>
<td colspan="3" style="width:19vw;height:4vh;background: #dd4444;opacity: 0.9;"><label style="margin-left:0.25vh;color:black;text-align: left;  font-weight: bold;">%</label></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vckj1218/0jps8qy9/7/#

Comment: I try to check the images and the JSFiddle example. I noticed that the JSFiddle example is not producing the table that you have shown in the image. So that sample code is not helpful for testing the issue. I suggest trying to post the example code that can produce the table that you have shown in the image. We will try to test the issue and try to provide you the suggestions for it. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: I again check the updated code but it is a similar code from the JSFiddle example that is not helpful for producing the issue. @VincentChin, I suggest you post the code that can generate the table that you have shown in the pictures.